# Would this question on setting an a writing iPad be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

i was thinking on asking this question

> When inspiration strikes i want to write however alot of the time i find that when this happens i'm 20 minutes away from my home computer by car. However i have an iPad with a Bluetooth Keyboard so i was thinking i should set it up for mobile writing and publishing.
>
> ### Requirements
>
> - ***Offline usage***: As when i am away from home i am also away from my wireless and being in IT i know how stupid it is to have an iPad using the phone network while i am on a pre-paid plan. All apps must work without a net connection
> - ***Transfer to a computer***: If i am home and i am on my computer i would like to continue what i have done on the ipad. any writing apps need to be able to transfer files to and from a PC weather it is via wireless or USB and if it needs another program on the computer that needs to be included too.
>
> ### Optional
>
> - ***Price***: it would be great if every app was free but good apps normally arn't. that being said if an app is free and has in-app pouches such as upgrading to a premium edition that should be noted, especially if it's a subscription to the premium edition (ie. Microsoft's OneNote)

it would be on topic in Software Recommendation but it would need to be split up (to which i only know 3 kinds of programs writing, publishing and dictionaries but i would like to know of other kinds of programs one would need) but I am wondering if this would be on topic here since it pertains to setting up a writing an publishing tablet.

if it isn't on-topic is the question salvageable? if so what do i need to do to make it on-topic?

Comment: This seems like something very useful for the Community Wiki once it gets going.